# Azure Container Instance in VNET how to get a FQDN

Tags: azure, containers, terraform, fqdn

When deploying a Container Instance which ISNT in a VNET we can specify a label "x" to get a FQDN i.e http://x.uksouth.azurecontainer.io/

If you deploy the container into a subnet it appears that you can no longer specify a label.

I'm using Terraform https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_group

Specifically "network_profile_id": conflicts with dns_name_label

In this case I assume you supposed to manage DNS yourself.

It doesnt *appear* you specify the private IP of the container?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure, it's impossible to set a static private IP address if you deploy the ACI in the VNet. You can expose the ACI in the VNet to the outside through the Application gateway, but when the IP address of the ACI changes, it can't work anymore. And you have no control over the ACI IP address.

Comment: Yeah - this is what I believe to be the case too. Not ideal.

Comment: @iasksillyquestions Yeah, you can feedback. And I also think it's a disadvantage of the ACI. It's a preview version. Maybe it will be fixed in the future. Well, if it's helpful please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#unsupported-networking-scenarios):

> Public IP or DNS label - Container groups deployed to a virtual network don't currently support exposing containers directly to the internet with a public IP address or a fully qualified domain name

Comment: This is true! However my question asks about setting a static private IP so that I can manage the DNS myself!